How to call a modular script from a parent
I have this line of code to try and retrieve a script from a (distant) parent
local signal = require(script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Script)

However, I am getting the error:

Attempted to call require with invalid arguments

Now, I understand that I am 100% using the wrong argument but I couldn't find the correct way to do it anywhere else, even after about 2 hours of internet searching.
Any ideas?
(P.S. The many many parents are because I got the model from the toolbox, and that was how it was structured, definitely completely inconvenient for a script.)

We would need to know the parent/child hierarchy of the relevant objects. All I can say from here is that script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Script is not a ModuleScript so cannot be used in require(). Also if you have that many nested objects, consider refactoring.
